# Oracle SQL count dates that do not exist between range of dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have range of dates:

```
| date |
| -------- | 
| 1/1/2022 |
| 2/1/2022 |
| 3/1/2022 |
| 5/1/2022 |
| 6/1/2022 |
| 7/1/2022 |
| 8/1/2022 |
| 10/1/2022 |
```

I want to get the dates that are not included between these dates, in this case `4/1 and 9/1`, I want the count of these dates, in this case `2`, so I want the count of dates that do not exist between a specific range of dates, how can I achieve that?

Comment: A new _column_? Can you show us the expected result too?

Comment: not new column, just the count of dates that are not in the range, i edited the post

Comment: Try using a less ambiguous date format e.g. 2022-01-01

Comment: Using the data and question provided, the count of dates NOT between 4/1 and 9/1 is 4, not 2.

Comment: max date - min date + 1 will give you the total number of dates in your range. count(distinct date) will give your table's number of (different) dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select (max(date) - min(date) + 1) - count(distinct date)
from table_name
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/cSKZloYA

`(max(date) - min(date) + 1)` will give the total number of days in the range.

`count(distinct date)` will be the number of existing (different) days in the table.

The difference between these is the number of non-existing days.

**Note:** `date` is a reserved word, so if it's the actual column name, it has to be delimited as `"date"`. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SQL_reserved_words)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LAG` analytic function to find the previous date and then work out the number of days difference and if it is more than 1 then you have that many missing days:

```sql
SELECT SUM(missing_dates) AS num_missing
FROM   (
  SELECT GREATEST("DATE" - LAG("DATE") OVER (ORDER BY "DATE") - 1, 0)
           AS missing_dates
  FROM   table_name
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ("DATE") AS
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-10' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| NUM_MISSING |
| --- |
| 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4WdaRgUy)